# Cannot use __construct in bundle checkbox class

Tags: magento2

I want to add the product image to bundle product page for each option. I chose to extend class
\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Checkbox

This class has no __construct method, but I have to use it because I want to use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image. When I define a construct method, the page crashes and throws an error
Call to a member function dispatch() on null

If I call parent::__construct, I receive a type error indicating the __construct methods do not match.

I have read that if the parent class does not have a __construct class, that I do not have to call parent, but in my case I cannot get this simple modification to work.

class Checkbox extends \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Checkbox
{

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
){
    $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you extend a class that extends from another class and has no __construct method, you must use the __construct of the parent which in this case is 
\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option

This fixed my issue.